# gtk_list_store_clear() function raises Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am writing a program using GTK in C. 
I am using GtkListStore to display some data coming from a database.
After a particular signal I want to remove all the rows in the GtkListStore.
I used gtk_list_store_clear() function, but it raises Segmentation Fault.

What is wrong with my code?

```
//Globally declared
GtkListStore *liststore2;

//Inside main() function
liststore2 = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "liststore2"));

//Inside signal handler function
gtk_list_store_clear(liststore2); //Error comes from here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you destroy the builder object (using `g_object_unref(builder)`) before the signal handler runs, liststore2 may point to freed memory.

That happens if liststore2 is free-standing (i.e., not ref'ed by something else, for example a GtkTreeView)

[gtk_builder_get_object](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-get-object) does *not* increment the reference count on object