# PyGTK TreeView ListStore clear() causes criticals

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I am writing a PyGTK application that includes a Gtk.TreeView. This TreeView uses a filter made by calling filter_new() on a Gtk/ListStore. This filter is what gets assigned to the TreeView, and is used for the custom search system. When refreshing the contents of the TreeView, as to prevent duplication I use the clear() method of the ListStore. This does not go very well. After refreshing, one element gets added to the list and then I see this string of errors:

```
(paddle.py:10751): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:09:01.370: gtk_tree_model_filter_get_value: assertion 'GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (model)->priv->stamp == iter->stamp' failed

(paddle.py:10751): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:09:01.370: gtk_tree_model_filter_get_path: assertion 'GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (model)->priv->stamp == iter->stamp' failed

(paddle.py:10751): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:09:01.370: gtk_tree_path_to_string: assertion 'path != NULL' failed

(paddle.py:10751): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:09:01.371: gtk_tree_model_filter_iter_next: assertion 'GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (model)->priv->stamp == iter->stamp' failed

(paddle.py:10751): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:09:01.371: ../../../../gtk/gtktreeview.c:6908 (do_validate_rows): assertion `gtk_tree_model_iter_next (tree_view->priv->model, &iter)' failed.
There is a disparity between the internal view of the GtkTreeView,
and the GtkTreeModel.  This generally means that the model has changed
without letting the view know.  Any display from now on is likely to
be incorrect.
```

This error is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961074/gtk-list-store-clear-function-raises-segmentation-fault-in-c), however that person does *not* provide code to fix the issue. It also appears to be referenced [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2002-July/msg00121.html), in a GNOME mailing thread from 2002. Anyone know how to fix this issue in modern gi/PyGTK? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks, Blue

Comment: Could you add an MCVE? I have a lot of setups like you described, and they work perfectly.

Comment: @theGTknerd hey mate! I actually forgot to update this question, but I have fixed the issue using GObject.idle_add(). Sorry for the trouble!